How to request issue details from the JIRA ServiceDesk REST API?
I have reviewed a number of other questions, but can't find anything specific to Jira ServiceDesk.
I am attempting to retrieve the details of a Jira issue I know to exist.  I am testing via the following CURL command:
curl -u my.name@myemployer.com:MyPassword https://servicedesk.myemployer.com/rest/servicedeskapi/request/TCA-1234

Where "servicedesk.myemployer.com" is a known good URL for the Jira Service Desk web UI, and the "my.name@myemployer.com" and "MyPassword" values are known to work when logging into Jira Service Desk.  The issue id "TCA-1234" is a known good value that can be viewed through the Jira Service Desk web UI.
I receive the following response:
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.94</h3></body></html>

I referred to the Jira Servide Desk REST API Reference but was unable to find a solution.
